# Git: Pull selected commit

Tags: git

It may be a duplicate, but my server now is ofline and I can found only very fussy answers to this.

So I need to pull commit 164183012b178c2f68891e1bff24e5c9a0c97222. How should I do that?

Comment: In git nearly every operation is offline, it seems like you are pretty new to git. I can suggest you the [Git Basics](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics) chapter of the gitpro book. Also the book in general is very helpful to get a good understanding of git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this tutorial: https://www.atlassian.com/en/git/tutorial/undoing-changes#!checkout

I think that you only need a **git checkout 164183012b178c2f68891e1bff24e5c9a0c97222**

Comment: I believe it is the right answer, but nothing happens after writing this. Should I write pull comand next or what to get these files? Thank you!!

Comment: Actually I just made a test and the git checkout command restores the state of the workspace.

Comment: oh. You are right - it works! Just added some kind of comment which cunfused me :) Thanks!

Comment: but there is one interesting thing. After using it, and later trying to use again `git pull` to get the newest version - tells to select branch. But `git checkout master` restores it and puts back on track

Answer (score 2):

Use git [`cherry-pick`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).

```
git cherry-pick 04566389ae36651daf3dfa117a1088d594632370
```

will pull the specific commit into your current branch.